# how to convert virtual DOM to an real DOM Element without render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

I use [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to take a screen shot of my page.however html2canvas need an element as a param, but I have a react app and I use a template to get the virtual DOMs.the template need to be reused many times

（so I don't want to render them then get the Element  by ref or getDocumentbyId(), that will be aweful）.

for instance:
 I got 1000 order data.and the templates will be 1000.then the virtual DOM object will be 1000.

Is there any way I can directly convert the virtual DOM Obj to an Element obj?

Comment: I don't get it, your terms are really confusing. What do you call a DOM string? What do you want at the end? H2C works from computed styles, so it needs Nodes that are children of an active Document.

Comment: yeah, I made it wrong, it's not a string, html2canvas need a Element Object as param. so I found if I just use a function to convert html string to a Element,it's stil not working. the nodes need to be actually children of the whole document.

Comment: BTW,the function which I mentioned coverting html string to an Element like this----
var str2DOMElement = function(html) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);             
    frame.contentDocument.open();
    frame.contentDocument.write(html);
    frame.contentDocument.close();
    var el = frame.contentDocument.body.firstChild;
    document.body.removeChild(frame);
    return el;
}
var markup = '<div><p>text here</p></div>';
var el = str2DOMElement(markup);

Comment: what I want is  to download pdfs of order detials.I've got that, I have to render the templates if I want to use H2C take screen shots. changing to this [phantom-html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html-to-pdf),which take a html string as param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

renderToString(<YouComponent>)
```

Comment: How does this help? What does this function do? By its name I'd say it returns a String right? How can this help OP which is trying to take a screeshot using html2canvas library?